# Should I insert my video card at PCIEX4 or PCIEX16?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

I have motherboard [GIGABYTE GA-H77-DS3H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4318&dl=1#manual) and video card [GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 660Ti](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4319#manual).
When I place it in PCIEX16 I have no video signal and motherboard makes 1 long and 2 fast beeps (which means video card problems). But it seams windows starts, because hard drive works after this.
When I place my video card in PCIEX4 everything works properly.

I updated all drivers and bios on motherboard (it seams video card has the last version).
I tried different bios options: disabling internal graphics, switching between "Init Display First" options.

Please suggest anything. I have no idea what to try next. Are there some jumpers or bios options to disable crossfire? Was it a bad idea to buy motherboard that supports crossfire and place GeForce in it?

UPDATE:
Yesterday I dismantle my PC to pieces and reassemble it again. After that all works perfectly. I am not sure what was wrong. Most likely there was some dust on CPU, because its the only thing I have not touched before.
Anyway, this was probably my fault :(

Comment: I am not alone http://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/49590-sapphire-7850-gpu-wont-detect-pcie-x16-z77-ud3h-works-fine-x8.html http://forums.tweaktown.com/asrock/49164-asrock-z77-extreme-6-doesnt-detect-my-sapphire-hd-7850-gpu.html http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=9754.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the x16 slot for the best possible video performance. On this particular motherboard, there are two slots that will physically hold an x16 graphics card, but the second slot, labeled PCIEX4, only runs at x4 (1/4 of the possible speed of the x16 slot).

In this particular case, my first suspicion is a defective motherboard. You can try updating the BIOS, or resetting it to defaults, and that might help. But most likely you're going to end up sending it back for replacement.

Comment: Agreed. Sounds like a broken motherboard (either in hardware or wrong BIOS/setup). The x16 slot has a higher maximum speed, which means your graphics cards will be about 5% to 10% faster in demanding games. See http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pci-express-2.0,1915-4.html for the performance differences for graphical card between the slots with different PCIe lanes.

Comment: My card can work in PCIEX16 slot if I set it to gen1. So I dont think my motherboard is broken, it looks more like some incompatibility, but I dont know what caused it :(